# Regexp union with word boundaries

Tags: ruby, regex, word-boundary

I have a list of patterns and I want to match a string against those patterns but I need to match only entire words, so I was looking for a way to dynamically insert word boundaries into the Regexp.union method but I am missing something.
Here is what I have tried

```
test_string = "lonewolf is lonely"
pattern_list = ["lonely", "wolf", "jungle"]
pattern_list.collect! { |pattern| pattern = "\b" + pattern + "\b"}
patterncollection = Regexp.union(pattern_list)
puts patterncollection
puts test_string.scan(patterncollection)
```

Results are empty and if I print the pattern collection I see that "\b" doesn't get escaped correctly.
I cannot insert the "\b" directly in the array as that list gets dynamically retrieved.
I have tried more than one option but still no luck.
Different approaches to the problem are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to move word boundary matchers outside of the union:

```
/\b(#{Regexp.union(pattern_list).source})\b/

▶ "lonewolf is lonely".scan /\b(#{Regexp.union(%w|lonely wolf jungle|).source})\b/
#⇒ [
#    [0] [
#        [0] "lonely"
#    ]
#  ]
```

Please also refer to the significant comment below. Basically, it suggests to “Use source unless you are absolutely positive you know what will happen. – the Tin Man”.

I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Be careful with embedding a regex in a regex, such as when using `Regexp.union`. `'foo'[/F O #{Regexp.union(['O', 'B'])}/mix]
# => nil` but `'foo'[/F O #{Regexp.union(['O', 'B']).source}/mix]
# => "foo"`. Use `source` unless you are absolutely positive you know what will happen.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks, I updated an answer. There is no issue with this particular input, but I completely agree it worth it to mention the corner cases.